# Connect AWS SSL certificate to Intercom Articles

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudfront

We have our support articles in Intercom Articles and need to attach a SSL certificate to the subdomain support.packaly.com. Intercom does not offer its own certificate so we need to do it through AWS. The complication is that we do not have our domain at AWS but at Google Domains.

We want to make the sub domain have a SSL certificate, and redirect it to Intercom help center. This is the article (video) that we use but the one difference is that we do not have the domain at AWS:

https://developers.intercom.com/installing-intercom/docs/set-up-your-custom-domain#section-how-to-configure-ssl-with-aws

Is there a workaround for connecting a AWS certificate for SSL with a Google Domains subdomain and redirecting it to the help center?

Comment: Consider putting CloudFront in front of the Intercom Articles install.

Comment: How do you mean this exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, https://medium.com/@getsee/make-your-intercom-help-center-https-with-a-custom-domain-2255cba66f50

that worked for me, most resources on the web state you need to set up an alias to point to the cloudfront distribution, but CNAME was the only method worked for me